# celery: Weird signs in result_backend (postgresql-db)

Tags: postgresql, celery

I am using a celery installation configured with a result_backend postgresql-database.

It's working ok so far, but I have a little problem with the "formatting" of the result in the db.

I am returning several values (a string, an Exception with an error-message, an int) from my task (function-name under @app.task).

But when I take a look into the table "celery_taskmeta"-table which celery writes to when result_backend-option is set, I see some more 'crypted' values next to the expected values ([screenshot of the select-result](http://euve31998.vserver.de/files/Unbenannt.png)).

Everything circled in red are the expected values. The 273 at the bottom for example is the octal representation of the int I returned.

Of course I can filter out all that unwanted stuff but if it contains some useful information or might be different under some other circumstances...

Does anyone know why there are those strange signs?

Thanks for your help,
Lukas

Comment: why are you querying the table directly? ideally you would get the data you need by doing `result = task.apply_async()` and then using `result.result`, `result.traceback` and so on.

Comment: My tasks are triggered via celery beat. And I need the result data at several other places. That's why I want it in a db..

Comment: yes. I get that. I'm saying don't query the db directly to get the results - use the celery API like I posted in my comment

Answer (score 0):

Don't query the database directly to get the result data - celery provides an API for this - see the [docs](http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/celery.result.html)

In your case you can do this to get the output of your task and any traceback:

```
cur.execute("SELECT task_id FROM celery_taskmeta WHERE date_done ...")
rows = cur.fetchall()

for row in rows:
    task_id = row[0]
    # you'll need to do something different if you have GroupResult
    result = celery.AsyncResult(task_id)  

    LOG.info(result.result)
    if result.traceback:
        LOG.error(result.traceback)
```